# CVSROOT may only specify a positive, non-zero, integer port

Tags: linux, version-control, cvs

I'm trying to compile and build our project on a Linux server machine getting the source code from a Windows repository. It seems that the repository path "c:\repository" is not reachable from Ubuntu due this error:

```
cvs login: CVSROOT may only specify a positive, non-zero, integer port (not `c:').
cvs login: Perhaps you entered a relative pathname?
```

How is it possible to checkout source from Windows repository from Ubuntu machine without using eclipse or any gui client? (Not available).

Comment: what about LDAP, samba (in order to mount your windows disk into your linux filesystem), then you can update the path and start working ...

Comment: How do you normally connect to this machine remotely?

Comment: From MacOS using Eclipse. I build on Mac OS and upload into the Ubuntu server